# using views instead of tables in EF 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

using views instead of tables in EF 6 MVC and getting the error below

Unable to update the EntitySet 'Test' because it has a DefiningQuery and no UpdateFunction element exists in the ModificationFunctionMapping element to support the current operation.

```
{
db.Entry(training).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();//here is the error in Stack Trace

}
```

I did everything in .edmx whatever was suggested in other posts like deleting DefiningQuery use Schema="dbo" instead of store: Schema="dbo" and I deleted other non-key columns under key tag but nothing worked what should I do?

Comment: You can't persist data changes to a view, you have to use the underlying table.

Comment: Views are only used to read data with SELECT query (including JOINs), you need the concrete entity table if you want to perform full CRUD.

Comment: Dont try to modify a view. Use a table instead of you want to modify the data

Comment: Thank you all for your reply I will not try to modify view